# Segue not being performed

Tags: ios, segue

After the user long clicks on a view, a popup is shown. Clicking on an item of this popup should perform a segue using this code:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"PlayerList" sender: self];
```

The controller is not displayed and I get this warning

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x11372890> on <TableViewController: 0xc3c93f0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

I don't understand what's causing the problem. The action of the item in the popup menu is performed with this code

```
[target performSelectorOnMainThread:_action withObject:self waitUntilDone:YES];
```

where `target` is the controller and `_action` should perform the segue.

Comment: The warning is moaning that the viewController that you are segueing from does not have its view on screen

Comment: Yes I understand the warning, but in fact the controller is currently being displayed full screen

Comment: Have you dismissed the alert before performing the segue?

Comment: Yes it's dismissed when clicking an item of the menu

Comment: We need more info here. More code or the story board as a screenshot or something.

Comment: Can you display/explain the hierarchy of view controllers? May be your tableViewController is not in navigation stack.